# Unable to select face

Tags: select

I'm following [this](https://youtu.be/wrzSrjAY69c?t=466) video tutorial and I'm unable to select the floor (by left-clicking on it) as the instructor does.  I've included a screencap of my UI and it seems to match his.  What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you have x-ray mode enabled. When x-ray mode is on you have to click the dot in the middle of the face to select it. If x-ray is disabled you can click anywhere on the face and it will be selected.

[image]

Comment: Aah, that was it.  I'm such a newb.  Thanks.